# Обработка завершения скрипта python

Tags: python

У меня возник вопрос, как обработать завершение работы кода в python. Для лучшего понимая, приведу в пример excepthook из модуля sys. Вот пример:

```
import sys
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        return

    logger.error("Uncaught exception", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))

sys.excepthook = handle_exception

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise RuntimeError("Test unhandled")
```

Здесь логируется каждое исключение. Нужно сделать что-то подобное, но именно при завершении программы.

Comment: `import signal`

Comment: спасибо, это определённо, то что мне нужно